# My Minecraft Can't Switch Out Of The 3D Anaglyph

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know some people have not known where the option is to turn it off. My question is how to turn it off. Before you mark this as a duplicate please note that whenever I click it to turn it off, my minecraft crashes and when I reload it it still is in the 3D Anaglyph mode.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to turn it off manually by editing the *options.txt* file, found in your *.minecraft* folder.

You'll want to look for the key that says `anaglyph3d`, and change the value after that from `true` to `false`, then save the file and open the game.

[image: Options]